Stock Inventory Issues
I'm in need of some help with my google sheets project.
I currently run a small business. And use sheets as a way to manage stock. I want to create QR codes to scan on item that will take me straight to the cell to adjust stock levels. However, when I insert a new row for an item, this changes the location for all QR codes already generated.
Is there a way around this? For example. If I have 3 rows of stock items. If I insert a row between row2 and row3 then row3 becomes Row4. But the QR code generated will still take me to Row3 which would now be incorrect 

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can use a formula to dynamically generate a URL which includes the cell address, and use that to generate the QR code. But since the reference has to be updated every time you add rows in between other rows, the QR codes will also update to point to the new location (it will keep changing), which may not be what you want. But at least, the QR code in a row will always point to the row it is in.
For example, assuming your QR code is to be in column C, put this in cell C2:
=IMAGE(
  CONCAT(
    "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chl=", 
    ENCODEURL(
      CONCAT(
        "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<SHEET-ID>/edit#gid=0&range=C",
        cell("row", $C2)
      )
    )
  ),
3)

You can now drag the cell to auto-fill the rest, and inserting rows should update the existing entries as well.

Encoded URLs
The problem space is that you are creating URLs encoded as QR codes. I will ignore the QR code wrinkle as it's largely irrelevant to the problem and refer to them interchangeably as URLs/links.
External References
Your URLs include references to a cell within your spreadsheet.They are valid when created and shared and correctly reflect the position of the linked row at that point in time. Unfortunately the links are not dynamic once removed from the spreadsheet so any change to the position of a linked row, whether from  inserting, removing, or sorting rows, immediately invalidates the link.
Dynamic Formula to Generate URL
Ashley Wilson's answer provides a way to generate valid links that are always up-to-date inside the spreadsheet but that doesn't address the problem created by using the links outside the spreadsheet which freezes them in time.
This a case where the left hand doesn't know what the right hand is doing.
Solutions
You need some glue in between the URL and the spreadsheet.
For example,

A hosted web page/server that can redirect URLs after querying the spreadsheet to determine the current row  of the intended product.
A web app that manages inventory so you don't reinvent the wheel.
You could simulate option #1 inside Sheets if looking for something quick and dirty.

Manually Simulate a Web Redirect in Sheets
This approach requires maintaining two links, one being static that will be shared externally and will never change, and another used internally that will be dynamic and change whenever target rows change position similar to the approach by Ashley Wilson
Permanent Link
This is the link to be shared externally.

If your products are in one tab Products, then Column 3 in a different tab prodLinks is where your external URLs will be mapped to.
Whenever you add a new product ID  to Products, you will hardcode its ID into prodLinks Column 1.
In prodLinks  Column 2 an  external link is created that references Column 3 of the same row.
You can shared that link externally.

Dynamic Link

prodLinks Column 3 contains a formula that generates a valid link for each Product ID from a lookup that captures the row position at the current point in time.
After clicking the external link generated in prodLinks Column 2 the destination/target cell in Column 3 contains a link to the correct ID in  Products.

Note:

prodLinks must never be sorted or have rows inserted or removed within the data.
It would be wise to add a hardcoded incrementing sort index assuming the IDs don't fill that need. In this way, if the rows in Sheet2 are accidentally rearranged, the original sort order can be restored. Manually adding the datetime whenever a new ID is added would also work.

At this point clicking on an external link would take you to its linked cell in prodLinks Column 3 where a second click would then take you to Products and the row that currently contains the product matching the ID
